# How to convert drawn vector feature from EPSG:900913 to EPSG:4326

Tags: openlayers, convert, coordinates, well-known-text

My script allows you to drawn shapes on an OpenLayers map, and then to get the WKT information from that shape, except the returned coordinates are in EPSG::900913 and I need them to be in lat/lon.

Comment: Welcome to GIS Stack Exchange! I'm not sure if you had trouble posting a relevant snippet from your code to indicate where you thought your problem might lie but I think you will need to do so in order to get assistance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to project (transform) the shape from EPSG:900913 (actually use the standard EPSG:3857) to  EPSG:4326.

You can use the following code:

```
var gcs=new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
var webMercator=new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3857");

/*I am assuming that you have a polygon in web mercator. You can do this for points and lines as well*/
var polygon_wgs84=poly.transform(webMercator, gcs);

//now you can convert the polygon to wkt
console.log(polygon_wgs84.toString(););
```